# Kali Linux Persistence on USB Drive

Tags: kali-linux

I heard of the persistence option of kali so i decided to keep my kali on a flash drive rather than dualbooting. So my question is will it be the same as a dualboot or single boot of kali or even a vm.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using the "persistence" option in Linux installed on a flash drive typically means that any changes you make on that instance is saved to the flash drive's storage. This contrasts to the typical "live" Linux, where everything is stored in RAM, so your changes are all lost upon a reboot.

So to answer your question, it isn't anything like a typical dualboot or singleboot. It is simply a portable install of the distribution, which means your changes will save on that flash drive. [This](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/what-is-persistent-linux/) can explain a bit more.

Comment: I tried both of them already but it seems that the dualboot is much faster in performance than the persistence usb, so if I bought a 128gb usb 3 flash drive will it be faster.

Comment: @Enigma read/write times of USB flash memory is typically much worse than a typical hard drive. Will probably be quicker than your current flash drive, but don't expect too much.